# How to remove image info tab from CKEditor?

Tags: ckeditor

I'm using CKEditor. I want to remove image info tab from image upload dialog box and keep upload tab.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for
Remove image info tab from CKEditor

```
if ( dialogName == 'image' )
    {
        // FCKConfig.ImageDlgHideAdvanced = true    
        dialogDefinition.removeContents( 'info' );
    }
```